# how do they use the native mac color-picker on this page : http://beta.theexpressiveweb.com/#!/css3-gradients

Tags: javascript, macos, color-picker

http://beta.theexpressiveweb.com/#!/css3-gradients

On mac, chrome or firefox, it uses native color-picker to change color. How ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just HTML5 input type called [`color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.color.html):

```
<input type="color">
```

More HTML5 input types you can find at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J972H/). Works only in modern browsers.

Comment: Those are "text" inputs, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you, looks like it works in firefox 28. (and didn't in previous version ? http://caniuse.com/input-color)

Comment: @Pointy see my updated answer. This will have same behaviour like text input in old browsers + in DOM. But in modern browsers it will show like system color picker.

Comment: @antyrat I know what you're talking about, but according to Firebug the two color picker widgets on that page are both `<input type="text">`

Comment: @Pointy for me they are inputs w/ type `color` see screenshot http://i.imgur.com/VkOCBfV.png

Comment: @antyrat oh you're right - it must feature-detect or browser sniff or something. I guess Firefox 23 doesn't support those yet, but Chrome (whatever) does.